# Using generated Stripe checkout button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments, webstorm, client-side

I'm trying to implement in my VueJS Project a checkout button generated from the Stripe Dashboard.

I feel like i'm not doing it the right way, so if you have advises i would like to hear them.

I have add `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>` in index.html.

[the 1st error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWCN0.png)

[the 2nd error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAVwR.png)

Here is my Vue component.

```
<template>
    <div>
    <button
            style="background-color:#6772E5;color:#FFF;padding:8px 12px;border:0;border-radius:4px;font-size:1em"
            id="checkout-button-MY_PLAN"
            role="link"
    >
        Checkout
    </button>

    <div id="error-message"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    (function() {

        let stripe = Stripe('MY_KEY');

        let checkoutButton = document.getElementById('MY_PLAN');
        checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {

            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                items: [{plan: 'MY_PLAN', quantity: 1}],

                successUrl: '',
                cancelUrl: '',
            })
                .then(function (result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        let displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
                        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
                    }
                });
        });
    })();
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

If i can't use Stripe in a VueJS Project how can i get around the problem without modifying all my project ?

Comment: Consider using a Vue specific tutorial (example: https://alligator.io/vuejs/stripe-elements-vue-integration/) or one of the various Vue packages for Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the first error where `Stripe` is undefined. That is likely because the Stripe.js library isn't loaded before that code runs. You'll need to ensure that you've included Stripe.js [1] with this tag in your HTML before any of your JavaScript using `Stripe` is executed. Note that it's not loaded `async`.

`<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>`

2. The second error is because when you're attempting to `getElementById` the ID that you're passing is not the same as the ID in the HTML for the button.

The button's ID is `checkout-button-MY_PLAN` and the ID you're trying to find the button with by passing is `MY_PLAN`. I would recommend updating your call to getElementById to:

`let checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-MY_PLAN');`

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/js/including